# NETGEAR *Security Alert* [58:84:C7] almost on daily basis, should I do anything?

Tags: 10.10, security, scanning

My Netgear wireless modem and router DG834PN has firewall installed and just recently I have been receiving almost daily 'security Alerts' stating;

> TCP Packet - Source:58.218.199.147 Destination:86.158.5.77 - [PORT SCAN].

They are all exactly the same source and destination. Is Ubuntu 10.10 secure or should I be doing something.

I can obviously adjust the firewall but what and how, if necessary..???

Many thanks,

Bruce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you install a server service, and manually configure it to use insecure settings, then yes, Ubuntu is secure.  Also your router should be ignoring those requests unless you have explicitly configured it to forward them to your computer.

Comment: You might block that source in your firewall, which might be a good idea.

Comment: I stupidly  took advice of comment above and was inundated so have tired of whole thing and have now gone back to original settings. Am also bored with receiving email so have turned that off as well. PSUSI, thank you very much for your advice and comment, much appreciated.B